# JavaScript Timer: Uses session start time not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, session-cookies

I am using JavaScript Timer for making quiz system which uses session start time to calculate required time for timer to work. It is working fine on some systems but not on all.
Can some on please help me..?

```
var ct = setInterval("calculate_time()",100); // Start clock.
function calculate_time()
{
   var end_time = "<?php echo $_SESSION['start_time']; ?>"; // Get end time from session variable (total time in seconds).
   var dt = new Date(); // Create date object.
   var time_stamp = dt.getTime()/1000; // Get current minutes (converted to seconds).
   var total_time = end_time - Math.round(time_stamp); // Subtract current seconds from total seconds to get seconds remaining.
   var mins = Math.floor(total_time / 60); // Extract minutes from seconds remaining.
   var secs = total_time - (mins * 60); // Extract remainder seconds if any.

   if(secs < 10){secs = "0" + secs;} // Check if seconds are less than 10 and add a 0 in front.
   document.getElementById("txt").value = mins + ":" + secs; // Display remaining minutes and seconds.

  // Check for end of time, stop clock and display message.
  if(mins <= 0)
  {
     if(secs <= 0 || mins < 0)
     {
        clearInterval(ct);
        document.getElementById("txt").value = "0:00";
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.action = "http://www.example.org/q/conflinux/expire_me.php";
        form.method = "post"
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();       
     }
   }
}

.....
.....

<form> <input id="txt" readonly> </input></form>
```

Comment: Also, include the browsers that this isn't working on.

Comment: remove these "quotation marks" 
ct = setInterval("calculate_time()",100);

Comment: Already in my answer and his new code

Comment: not working on chrome 33.0.1750.117 m with win 8 or win 7

Answer (score 1):

This works for me - I set the ct as a global var and only store the end time once

Please change `setInterval("calculate_time()",100);` to `setInterval(calculate_time,100);`

You can create your own namespace if you do not want to pollute the global scope

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/32x46/)

```
var ct, end_time = <?php echo $_SESSION['start_time']; ?>; // Get end time from session variable (total time in seconds). 

window.onload=function() { // make sure the output field exists
  ct = setInterval(calculate_time,100); // Start clock.
}
function calculate_time() {
  var dt = new Date(); // Create date object.
  var time_stamp = dt.getTime()/1000; // Get current minutes (converted to seconds).
  var total_time = end_time - Math.round(time_stamp); // Subtract current seconds from total seconds to get seconds remaining.
  var mins = Math.floor(total_time / 60); // Extract minutes from seconds remaining.
  var secs = total_time - (mins * 60); // Extract remainder seconds if any.
  if(secs < 10){secs = "0" + secs;} // Check if seconds are less than 10 and add a 0 in front.
  document.getElementById("txt").value = mins + ":" + secs; // Display remaining minutes and seconds.
// Check for end of time, stop clock and display message.
  if(mins <= 0) {
    if(secs <= 0 || mins < 0)  {
     clearInterval(ct);
     document.getElementById("txt").value = "0:00";
     var form = document.createElement("form");
     form.action = "http://www.example.org/q/conflinux/expire_me.php";
     form.method = "post"
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     form.submit();
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Sir its not working check it out here...[link](http://2014.pragyaa.org/q/conflinux/) use ID: 326599 email: shubhamtakode@gmail.com

Comment: I get a countdown of 25 minutes in Chrome. Where do you have issues? If IE, try to press F12 to see if there isa console error

Comment: timer is working fine on chorme Version 32.0.1700.107 m but shows nothing or 0:00 on chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m

Comment: I am on 33.0.1750.117 on Mac - does the counter also not work from my fiddle?

Comment: Sir i didnt get you? I am using win 8.

Comment: My Chrome 33 on Mac works. I can test Chrome 33 on Win 8 tomorrow

Comment: Tested now in v33 in XP and win7 - no issues